# Class instance fields from json object returning null

Tags: java, json

I am trying to get class instance from JSON response. My json response looks like this: [image]

My class looks for example looks like this:

```
    private String brandName;
    @OneToMany(targetEntity=Store.class)
    private List<Store> stores;
    private String currency;
    private String title;



    public Product (){}

    public String getBrandName() {
        return brandName;
    }

    public void setBrandName(String brandName) {
        this.brandName = brandName;
    }


    @OneToMany(targetEntity=Store.class)
    public List<Store> getStores() {
        return stores;
    }
    @OneToMany(targetEntity=Store.class)
    public void setStores(List<Store> stores) {
        this.stores = stores;
    }


    public String getCurrency() {
        return currency;
    }

    public void setCurrency(String currency) {
        this.currency = currency;
    }

    public String getTitle() {
        return title;
    }

    public void setTitle(String title) {
        this.title = title;
    }
```

So i'm trying to create class from json with google Gson api like this:

```
private Gson gson = new Gson();
...
product = this.gson.fromJson(this.http.get(url), Product.class);
```

But after i'm get a class from gson api i see that all of my class fields is null. I am also trying to add `@JsonProperty` to my entity fields but it's doesn't work. And also trying to get instance with `ObjectMapper`, but result was null. What i'm doing wrong ?

Comment: Have debugged "this.http.get(url)" that is returning something not null? I mean Are you sure you get same structure that you displayed on your screenshot?

Comment: @nineunderground yes, the "this.http.get(url)" did not returning null because the pic on the post is the result of this method.  I have not the same structure because i delete some fields because i don't need them. I think it is must work. Or i need identical structure as in json and not delete fields that i don't need ?

Comment: Could you please print that JSON String?

Comment: @nineunderground yes, there is it - https://pastebin.com/jKMEN6mj.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I though that is not a valid instance for your class. That's an HTTP Response.
If you see your item starts after value "products" which by the way it's an array, even that response only returns one.
So, you need to get only that part of the item.

So try to create a whole JSON representation with following:

```
JSONObject myObject = new JSONObject(result);
```

And then get only that... getResult() I guess. And finally you pass that to the Gson method

Comment: the problem was in the structure of json. So you was right, i was just need to get the part of json. thnks